# How to handle HttpServerErrorException?

Tags: java, spring, https, exception

I am currently using java and spring boot to get authorized in a API. It depends on the value that users inserts to see weather the api is valid or not.If it's valid it would basically display data.

**Main Problem**

When user enters wrong value in the end of the api. I get error 500 "internal server error" and it stops my spring application. I want to create an exception where it would catch this error and spits out that there's an error 500 rather than stopping my application. Even with wrong value I want my application to continue running.

**Error**

When users enter the wrong params I receive an error below

```
 org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
```

How can I override it, so that even if user enter wrong data, Don't break my application and continue running. Just display Null for data.

**Attempt to handle**

I was able to allow my application to continue running with following code below

```
try {  //OauthRestTemplate exhanges credentials for api access
 } catch (HttpServerErrorException e ) {                
   e.getStatusCode();
   logger.info(e + "Server bypass, Continue running application");
    //allow application to continue running but does not display the actual message that would be on the api.
        }
  //output
   org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server ErrorServer bypass, Continue running application
```

But I want it to by pass the status 500 and display the actual message when I am on the api with wrong parameters. I should receive the same values that are printed on the api. Example Below

```
{"message":"Physical resource does not exist for mac address: D","code":"APRO-2001","timestamp":1490895756655,"type":"com.server.camp.framework.exception.ErrorResponse","status":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"}
```

Comment: @FarazDurrani Thank you!, I will attempt that tomorrow when I get on my programming computer.

Comment: forget about it. That solution is not correct. Instead, take a look at this: http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/07/handling-json-error-object-responses-with-springs-resttemplate

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code"_ are considered off-topic.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: @JimGarrison The problem is clear, and the OP needs help accomplishing the tasks. I do not need no code samples just a hint would help answer my question.

Comment: Without seeing your code nobody can possibly help. The question is off-topic.

Comment: @JimGarrison Revised.

Comment: You can't 'handle' a 500 error at the client. The problem is at the server, and only the server knows what it was. Examine the server logs. Maybe there was an error at the client, or maybe at the server. Whatever the case, it is far more likely to be a coding error than something you can handle at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this applies to your problem (as you did not provide your code yet) but this might help:

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="No such Order")  // 404
 public class OrderNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
     // ...
 }
```

You can basically add the @ResponseStatus to a function inside your class, set the value to the appropriate one (in your case INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR as shown [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html#INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)).

I hope this helps! If not, please provide your code.

Maybe this link about Exception-Handling in spring might help: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc